# run zsh script in specified folder

Tags: zsh

How to run zsh script in specified folder? How to specify a folder to run a script:

```
zsh script_name.sh
```

Documents said that: "-s Force shell to read commands from the standard input.  If the -s flag is not present and an argument is given, the first argument is taken to be the pathname of a script to execute." but it does not work.

What is the difference between `zsh -c ~/path1/ script1.sh` (2 parameters) and `zsh -c ~/path1/script1.sh`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should just open a subshell, Execute the following from zsh *or bash* (including the parentheses):

```
(cd ~/path1 && source script1.sh)
```

Note: If your script is written for zsh, name it `script1.zsh` instead, since zsh syntax is not retro-compatible with old sh's.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
zsh -c "cd ~/path1 && ./script_name.sh"
```